# Wikipedia database dump - UTF8 charset

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to open in python3 wikipedia database [dump file](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/arzwiki/latest/arzwiki-latest-langlinks.sql.gz). I unpack in linux this file with gzip command and try open with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

with open('dump.sql', 'r') as file:
        for i in file:
                print(i)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 250-251: invalid continuation byte
```

Linux command `file -i dump.sql` shows utf8 charset. Where can be a problem?

I found more info [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Dump_format) but this file is from 4.7.2017 so this cannot be a problem.

> The dumps may contain non-Unicode (UTF8) characters in older text revisions due to lenient charset validation in the earlier MediaWiki releases (2004 or so). For instance, zhwiki-20130102-langlinks.sql.gz contained some copy and pasted iso8859-1 "ö" characters; as the langlinks table is generated on parsing, a null edit or forcelinkupdate to the page was enough to fix it.

So how can I process wikipedia database dumps files in python?

Comment: Use the `errors` argument to `open()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open for possible values. Or alternatively surround with `try` / `except` and decode the string manually.

Comment: I copied / pasted your code, ungz the dump, run your program: it works.

Comment: The problem lies in ``define table  … `ll_title` varbinary(255)`` as the length for `VARBINARY` is a length in _bytes_ rather than in characters. For instance, the trailing word of `ll_title` in record `(99569,'bn','টেমপ্লেট:এক …')` at line 43 is unhappily truncated (in `utf-8` binary representation) as `\x20\xe0\xa6\x96\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6'` i.e. `\x20`=a space, `xe0\xa6\x96`=খ (U+0996, OtherLetter) Bengali Letter Kha, `\xe0\xa7\x87`= ে (U+09C7, SpacingCombiningMark) Bengali Vowel Sign E, `\xe0\xa6`= **missing continuation byte**.

Comment: `with open( 'dump.sql', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:` should work.